# Use Note Boards, but MySite is disabled

Tags: web-part, mysite, comments

I set up an Enterprise WIKI for our department. I want to add a Note Board to the pages in order to enable discussions on the articles. Unfortunately, the IT told me that MySite is disabled in general. Is there a workaround, which provides similar features, but does not request MySite to be activated?

Thank you very much!

ZD14

We use Sharepoint 2010.

Comment: Maybe you could create a list using the template "Discssuion board" that would suit your needs?

Comment: Hi Christoffer,
Thank you for your reply! I was busy, sorry for replying late!

I don't know, somehow either i've gotten you wrong or you've gotten me wrong! :P

I want to implement a comment section on every wiki pages.

In case I've gotten you wrong, can you please specify.

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Hello,

I had a closer look on the template "Discussion board"! To me it seems that this Workaround might be an option.
Can I add a new discussion for every page someone adds to the wiki automatically and show the discussion board on every page filtering by ist title?

Comment: That could actually work.. but then i would create a wiki page template the has a query url/title filter so have it set up everytime you create a new wiki page. But you are on the right track